# Number of elements of order $2$ in $U(n)$

Tags: abstract-algebra

I  have  to  find  out  how  many  elements  of  $Z/8Z$ that  satisfy the  equation $x^{2}=1$

Clearly  the  solutions  are  the  elements  of  $U(n)$  that  have  order  $2$.

Manually  I  checked  them  to be $\bar 1$,$\bar 3$, $\bar 5$,$\bar 7$.

I  can see  that  for  any $n$, $n-1$  has  order  $2$  in $U(n)$ . What  about  the others like  what  are  some  theories  to  use  here  so  as  to  find  elements  of  a  particular  order  in  $Z_{n}$ without  checking  manually.

Thanks  for  any  help.

Comment: all the elements of order 1 or 2

Answer (score 1):

This is for order $2$, general $n$.  Factor $n$ as $2^{a_0}p_1^{a_1}\cdots p_k^{a_k}$ where the $p_i$ are distinct odd primes.

Modulo $2^{a_0}$, there is one element of order $\le 2$ if $a_0=1$, there are two if $a_0=2$, and there are four if $a_0\ge 3$. The situation for odd primes is simpler. Only $1$ and $-1$ have order $\le 2$ modulo $p_i^{a_i}$.

The only way to have order $\le 2$ modulo $n$ is to have order $\le 2$ modulo $2^{a_0}$ and the $p_i^{a_i}$ and order $2$ modulo at least one of these.

To produce all possibilities, we use the Chinese Remainder Theorem on all possible combinations of elements of order $\le 2$ modulo the prime powers in the prime power decomposition of $n$ (we throw away the one element of order $1$).

The situation is simplest when $n$ is odd. Then we get $2^k-1$ elements of order $2$.

For $2^a$ where $a\ge 3$, the elements of order $\le 2$ are $1$, $-1$, $2^{a-1}-1$, and $2^{a-1}+1$.